# RecyclerView.Adapter - Displayed data not correct

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm struggling a little bit with RecyclerView.Adapter. The problem is that RecyclerView sometimes mixes up views, but not with the underlying data but with what is displayed. And it happens only on something around 5% of items on the screen. Sometimes TextViews got their text completely from outter space, for example it suppose to display '1' but it displays '50' but that number doesn't exist anywhere in the application because text is autoincremented while I'm creating items and I've got like 2 of them, also when I'm checking what items are in the database on which position everything is fine, what's more bizzare, when I debugged onBindViewHolder, the holder got all the right data, and set it to the views, but the screen got something different, so it seems like the errors are generated somewhere after onBindViewHolder. Just to be clear, I'm implementing all the methods getItemId, hasStableIds, getItem properly and they indeed return correct items for given positions in onBindViewHolder.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Item item = mProvider.getItem(position);
    int stickerSize = (int) (screenWidth * Const.STICKER_GRID_PROP);
    Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(Const.backgroundNoteIDs[item.backgroundId])
            .into(holder.background);
    Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(Const.stickerIDs[item.stickerId])
            .resize(stickerSize, stickerSize)
            .centerInside()
            .into(holder.sticker);
    int paddingHorizontal = (int) (screenWidth * Const.GRID_TEXT_PADDING_HORIZONTAL_PROP);
    int paddingVertical = (int) (screenWidth * Const.GRID_TEXT_PADDING_VERTICAL_PROP);

    switch(item.type) {
        case Const.NOTE:
            holder.noteText.setText(item.note.text);
            holder.checklistItemsLayout.removeAllViews();
            holder.checklistLines.setImageBitmap(null);
            holder.noteText.setTextSize(screenWidth * Const.GRID_TEXT_SIZE_PROP);
            holder.noteText.setPadding(paddingHorizontal, paddingVertical, paddingHorizontal, paddingVertical);
            break;
        case Const.CHECKLIST:
            holder.noteText.setText(null);
            holder.checklistItemsLayout.setPadding(paddingHorizontal, paddingVertical, paddingHorizontal, paddingVertical);
            Iterator<ChecklistItem> it = item.checklist.checklistItems.iterator();
            int i = 0;
            while(it.hasNext() && i < 4)
            {
                ChecklistItem checklistItem = it.next();
                final TextView textView = new TextView(mContext);
                textView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
                textView.setText(checklistItem.text);
                int drawable;
                if(checklistItem.checkStatement) {
                    drawable = R.drawable.checked;
                } else {
                    drawable = R.drawable.unchecked;
                }
                Picasso.with(mContext)
                        .load(drawable)
                        .resize((int) (stickerSize * 0.25f), (int) (stickerSize * 0.25f))
                        .centerInside()
                        .into(new Target() {
                            @Override
                            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                                Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(mResources, bitmap);
                                textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(d, null, null, null);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                            }
                        });
                Picasso.with(mContext)
                        .load(R.drawable.karteczka_linie)
                        .resize( (int) (screenWidth * Const.MENU_BIG_BUTTON_PROP), (int) (screenWidth * Const.MENU_BIG_BUTTON_PROP))
                        .centerInside()
                        .into(holder.checklistLines);
                textView.setTextSize(screenWidth * Const.GRID_TEXT_SIZE_PROP);
                holder.checklistItemsLayout.addView(textView);
                i++;
            }
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("onBindViewHolder got item without any type");
    }
}
```

---

```
public Item getItem(int index) {
    return mItems.get(index);
}
```

---

```
public static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements
        ItemTouchHelperViewHolder {
    public TextView noteText;
    public ImageView background;
    public ImageView checklistLines;
    public ImageView sticker;
    public LinearLayout checklistItemsLayout;

    public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        noteText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_text);
        background = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_background);
        checklistLines = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checklist_lines);
        sticker = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_sticker);
        checklistItemsLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checklist_items);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick " + getItemId());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected() {
        itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClear() {
        itemView.setBackgroundColor(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, so here's the solution, I forgot to remove all views from the checklistItemsLayout in the ViewHolder, which inflates one of two types of items I display, so everytime specific **ViewHolder was reused**, TextViews were added properly but they were stacked on old ones so they didn't had space to show up, but this happened only when ViewHolder was reused on the same type of the item.

**You need to remember to reload every element from the ViewHolder in onBindViewHolder, otherwise You might have some leftovers from other items previously used in this ViewHolder like I did**

Here's the fixed code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ...

    switch(item.type) {
        case Const.NOTE:
            holder.noteText.setText(item.note.text);
            holder.checklistItemsLayout.removeAllViews();
            holder.checklistLines.setImageBitmap(null);
            holder.noteText.setTextSize(screenWidth * Const.GRID_TEXT_SIZE_PROP);
            holder.noteText.setPadding(paddingHorizontal, paddingVertical, paddingHorizontal, paddingVertical);
            break;
        case Const.CHECKLIST:

            //This line was missing
            holder.checklistItemsLayout.removeAllViews();

            holder.noteText.setText(null);
            holder.checklistItemsLayout.setPadding(paddingHorizontal, paddingVertical, paddingHorizontal, paddingVertical);
            Iterator<ChecklistItem> it = item.checklist.checklistItems.iterator();
            int i = 0;
            while(it.hasNext() && i < 4)
            {
             ...
            }

    }
}
```